# Get a slow animations on <h1> using css when mouse out from de <h1> tag

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transitions

When I position the cursor over my `h1` element it scales by 2, so when the cursor leaves the `h1` I want it to return to its normal size but in the same way...slowly!

```
.navBar h1:hover {
  color: rgb(248, 250, 144);
  transform: scale(1.7);
  transition: linear 1s;
  z-index: 10;
  text-shadow: 2px 8px 5px 1px rgba(224, 224, 117, 0.952);
}
```

Comment: I don't know if that's intended, but when using `transfor: scale(n)` your title is going to scale to the left, overflowing the window frame. You should scale it by increasing the `font-size` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the transition setting to the non-hover state instead of the hover rule:

```css
.navBar h1 {
  transition: linear 1s;
}

.navBar h1:hover {
  color: rgb(248, 250, 144);
  transform: scale(1.7);
  z-index: 10;
  text-shadow: 2px 8px 5px 1px rgba(224, 224, 117, 0.952);
}
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <h1>This is an H1 Header</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks it was in front of me all time ..Im just a beginner

Comment: And then you no longer need the `transition` declaration in the hover ruleset.

Answer (score -1):

Use :not(:hover) to apply another transition

```
.navBar h1:hover {
  color: rgb(248, 250, 144);
  transform: scale(1.7);
  transition: linear 1s;
  z-index: 10;
  text-shadow: 2px 8px 5px 1px rgba(224, 224, 117, 0.952);
}

.navBar h1:not(:hover){
  transform: scale(1.7);
  transition: linear 2s;
}
```